# Why Int32.Parse(ReadOnlySpan<char> s...) overload is not supported in the full .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net

I was trying to understand what's the reason behind not supporting [Int32.Parse overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netcore-2.1#System_Int32_Parse_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_) that takes `ReadOnlySpan<char>` in full .NET framework. It is supported in .NET Core 2.1, but it is missing from the full .NET framework [Int32.Parse overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

I can confirm this in VS as well, I can use the overload in .NET core project, but as soon as I switch to .NET framework (4.7) this overload is missing.

Comment: Because `ReadOnlySpan` is missing from the full .NET to begin with?

Comment: For now, those overloads are only supported by .NET Core, nothing else. You can switch which target framework you want to look at the documentation for in that link you posted by changing it all the way to the left, when you switch to anything but .NET Core 2.1, the overloads using spans disappear. Hopefully, Microsoft will add them soon in some way.

Comment: @GSerg good point, installed `System.Memory` nuget package blindly in .NET Core project & was under impression it's not part of .NET Core either. Please post your comment, I'll mark it as an answer.